# Switching ancestors order breaks initialization?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is from Django application, using multiple inheritance in a custom form:

```
from django import forms

class CommonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'CommonForm.__init__'
        super(CommonForm, self).__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        print 'CommonForm.__init__ FINISHED'
        self._request = request

class MyMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'MyMixin.__init__'
        super(MyMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print 'MyMixin.__init__ FINISHED'

class CustomForm(CommonForm, MyMixin):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'CustomForm.__init__'
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        print 'CustomForm.__init__ FINISHED'

# weird initialization:
frm = CustomForm(http_request)

# outputs:
CustomForm.__init__
CommonForm.__init__
CommonForm.__init__ FINISHED
CustomForm.__init__ FINISHED
```

**What can cause `MyMixin.__init__` being skipped ?!**
There is no error message, no exception being thrown, nothing …

If I switch order of class inheritance to

```
class CustomForm(MyMixin, CommonForm):
```

all initializers are suddenly called as expected:

```
frm = CustomForm(http_request)

CustomForm.__init__
MyMixin.__init__
CommonForm.__init__
CommonForm.__init__ FINISHED
MyMixin.__init__ FINISHED
CustomForm.__init__ FINISHED
```

Can anybody explain what is going on here ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why that is happening, but I do know that you shouldn't be using super() when using multiple inheritance, instead you should:

```
    CommonForm.__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
    MyMixin.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here's a good example of this: http://www.python-course.eu/python3_multiple_inheritance.php

Comment: `super()` is ok even in case of multiple inheritance. I've got an answer on another server, the issue is with Django's BaseForm init missing super() call. Possible bug. Explicit init calls like in your example is the way how to work around this issue. Else super() may be used as a standard way.

Comment: Okay, good to know. That issue is probably why the examples I looked up had explicit init calls